# AllowAnonymous not working with OpenId Connect authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have a Razor pages app thats using both OpenId Connect and JWT Bearer authentication - the first for the Razor pages UI, the second is for some API endpoints.

But any Razor pages that have AllowAnonymous applied give a 401 Unauthorized error. This is Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // need to specify which scheme to use as default, we choose the web app here
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Diagnostics"); // 401 on any page under here

    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Navigating to any page under /Diagnostics when not logged in gives 401. All other pages will redirect to the Microsoft login page (as expected).

Project is .NET 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid setting the default policy and set only the fallback policy. Both routes will then behave as expected. The API will `fall back` to OAuth API security whenever a route is not anonymous.

I find this a little unintuitive, and previous incarnations of the .NET API technology stack worked differently.